# htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])

Tags: forms, action

```
if($_POST) {

$mysql_pass = '';

$connect = @mysql_connect($_POST['dbHost'], $_POST['dbUser'], $mysql_pass); 

 if($connect) {
if(@mysql_select_db($_POST['dbName'])) {
    $dir =  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
    $redirectUrl = str_replace("configForm.php","site/index", $dir);
    print $redirectUrl; exit;
    $dbConf = dirname(__FILE__).'/dbConfig/dbconf.php';
    $handle = fopen($dbConf, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$dbConf);
    $data = '<?php $userName="'.$_POST['dbUser'].'";'."\n";
    $data .= '$passWord=" ";'."\n";
    $data .= '$dbName="'.$_POST['dbName'].'";'."\n";
    $data .= '$host="'.$_POST['dbHost'].'"; ?>';
    fwrite($handle, $data);
    header('Location: site/index'); 
}
else {
  $error = 'Could not select database.';
}
}
```

else
   $error = 'Not connected';
}

when the code above was executed, my webpage just displayed "localhost/www-edusec/site/index". i do not know where i do it wrong. my form action is like below:

`<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">`

Answer (score 0):

The `action` attribute defaults to the current page anyway, so that piece of code is surely redundant.

The problem is `PHP_SELF` returns the path to the file too. Just get rid of the action line completely and it should work fine.

EDIT:

Also, the reason your script is cutting off half way, you have an `exit;` after it prints out the directory.

Comment: I did some edit based on what you've said. But, i got this message "
CDbException

CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection."

Comment: That's a different problem with your SQL, I suggest you ask another question on here with that error and all of your PHP code in relation to connecting, or expand this one with your SQL code.